# Python f5-sdk: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'icontrol'

Tags: python, python-3.x, f5

I was trying 
https://f5-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
when this problem occurred.

```
>>> from f5.bigip import ManagementRoot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\f5_sdk-3.0.21-py3.6.egg\f5\bigip\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from icontrol.session import iControlRESTSession
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'icontrol'
>>>

>>> import f5.bigip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\f5_sdk-3.0.21-py3.6.egg\f5\bigip\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from icontrol.session import iControlRESTSession
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'icontrol'
>>>
```

What was the problem here and how to solve it?

Comment: What exactly you were trying? Where did you find the above code? Obviously you're missing a package named `icontrol`

Comment: @KostasCharitidis, https://f5-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install both of these modules using pip.

```
pip install f5-sdk
pip install f5-icontrol-rest
```